# Put a link in a PDF file with xsl-fo

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt

I used the code given in the answer at [FOP XSL-FO Anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703548/fop-xsl-fo-anchor-in-an-external-destination) to put a link in the PDF file being generated by my xsl-fo code. The code I use is

```
<fo:table-row font-size="8pt">
  <fo:table-cell text-align="left" number-columns-spanned="12" padding-left="0.1cm" padding-top="0.1cm" border-left="0.50pt solid black" border-right="0.50pt solid black"  >                       
    <fo:block>
        <fo:basic-link 
            external-destination="url('http://www.moga.mo.gov/mostatutes/stathtml/26000003921.html)" 
            color="blue" text-decoration="underline">
             http://www.moga.mo.gov/mostatutes/stathtml/26000003921.html
       </fo:basic-link> 
    </fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

The link generated in the PDF file is

`file:///C:/Users/pondek/Appdata/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary%20Internet%20Files/Content.IE5/NJ1Y1AFR/'http://www.moga.mo.gov/mostatutes/stathtml/26000003921.html`

I don't know if it matters but I am using Rad 8.5 on a PC using Windows 7Professional.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left off the closing '.  It should have been

```
external-destination="url('http://www.moga.mo.gov/mostatutes/stathtml/26000003921.html')"
```

instead of

```
external-destination="url('http://www.moga.mo.gov/mostatutes/stathtml/26000003921.html)"
```